# Unoptimized clang++ code generates unneeded "movl $0, -4(%rbp)" in a trivial main()

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, llvm, x86-64

I created a minimal C++ program:

```
int main() {
    return 1234;
}
```

and compiled it with clang++5.0 with optimization disabled (the default `-O0`). [The resulting assembly code is](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5HhYEA1AFsmsiAEp5HAOx8ADAEF5R%2BcUwExLebS4BmACwcbe/doAiHAx/2yFAM1So6po6XsYmZhZWtg5OXm5SaozSAKxSpCzSummo0gDC/PzywmISmra0aQSZCYkA1iA2WgB0dgBsNgCcWq0ddslcdnYdrUlSdmmKdLq66dWkOVJpgiAzVVJZiXCwMFA7EEhoigAOeAyYZBQQhydnxCjMbMnTpL6nBOfLEAD6P7qUiQAjOYA2RMYgAT2kFVIh0UmDkAHkWAxIes0lhlGwznN8KZkAQ8AA3TDLNGkTAAD0wyBE7yhaR8mAYcyoAEcROdUTYmlwmtCzmwCEh6EdTISEQCqNSqt9fpRBHgAF6Ks60J5tLQADhstE6Ni4lBELCwrxYmHQlDOwHhFsgyVIMykFTULsSAuAQropFFmHFkullB%2BXz%2B1AAihyIfraLp9U8uLQ7JquEm2vZdK1aJR8IIjsxUQkhEqVZg1boNdrdR19YbjZhTebLZhrcb4PbHc7XYx4R7hS7SARiHhJk6Cw92AVeIw8ADlpBEqgjgTUCxSQBaQQEdCOVzAFgiCc8Wi0eTrzcMafb88Azi8QqrhG6E%2B%2BYnEAGoQSYVdMQSKJaicSSLQbopGkGRkgsFKaq0q6tHY8jIGO8jJE0ugofIEC4IQJBlDqpDyLkqDHKc5w4UB%2BEHpU1R9ggmBMFgdzqKQ9RPKM4ykJMWiobYXC6JqmpaB0HS0B0XBaHYszgdISwrP2VGkFsiAgKIBBHLS5CUNcxF3PQ5pYdpwFSKkElZPM0jcDq8gAO6EAg8iQdBsHwYhyGoSZawbIkNF0ec/ysRMIBcB0TTdAJR48bxuhaFwrRcMZ2RSUIMnuTUTEgImPJ2JFmViVlWWjDYoFzAslFopsex7AchE3Oc6lXFVWkgMAWg2C8bwfIGcqMUCZIgiwYKotCsLwgQSIojimCYsA2Jkri0pEiScyUtStKSCO5ByEyLLspy0jcry/Ldp6IpihKUr4h1wbykWqrqq0Wo6nqBoQEaJqyA2EBWja8BHg6pAjq6bqHcK3onf652ypdYYRuCUYxlwcYJkmKbtJlGZZngOZ5lJiQKsqN1lndFaPTWr1mhaH1Nl9kA/e2NR9u6R19gOQ70m6rDjrek5XrOjELkuK7SKeW42Due4HkeJ4AOpMAwDAng%2Bf4lIBBlGWBJkQVBMFwcAyDIPIzQ2OhmFEMQpF4QRRG3DhXAaPknM8CVHmkF59G%2BcxMzMmM/liShrStMkgmdH0TzDHFpmLIlqxyQp%2BxKbSqkELVmm3AF5L4CbdAq4VklSOZXBWTZdma45Ot6wbjspS7PmMZ7bGTPDTRVmm6a6MkgwdGWYfFZHsmlXUIDJLQwUB/DIkjyPIyewVXcJclfb1DFTTJDYrS6LYrd2FoyTqqMXD%2BdGMxq/FEdzwZe8zyfVGJC%2BCrLmlQA):

```
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  movl $1234, %eax # imm = 0x4D2
  movl $0, -4(%rbp)
  popq %rbp
  retq
```

I understand most of the lines, but I do not understand the "movl $0, -4(%rbp)". It seems the program initializes some local variable to 0. Why?

What compiler-internal detail leads to this store that doesn't correspond to anything in the source?

Comment: Because you forgot to enable optimization. Use `-O2`.

Comment: The “why” part is answered trivially by “because you compiled with optimizations turned off.”  The compiler tends to generate weird code if you forbid it to optimize oddities away.

Comment: But why is this line there in the first place?

Comment: Because the compiler can do what it wants.  It's probably some sort of sentinel for something. It could be used to detect buffer overflows.

Comment: IDK, but we can narrow it down to `main` being "special".  https://godbolt.org/g/fjYKjH.  clang doesn't do it for functions with different names.  Unfortunately `clang -fverbose-asm` doesn't label each line in as much detail as gcc, so we can't see why from that.  Maybe if we looked at the LLVM-IR or other compiler internals for `-O0` mode.

Comment: @NathanOliver: A stack canary doesn't make sense.  It's not reading it back, and it's in the red-zone below RSP.  It looks nothing like what `gcc -fstack-protector-strong` does.  It's probably some hidden variable, or maybe leftover from some kind of difference between how clang handles `main(void)` and `main(int argc, char**argv)`, with `main` being special.

Comment: It could be because apparently _"reaching the end of the main() function is equivalent to returning 0"_ ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/547981)). So the compiler was just setting up for that case and due to optimizations off, it did not remove that code.

Comment: @Jester this is very interesting, but the return value of main is put in the register eax, not on the stack...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** : In unoptimized code your CLANG++ set aside 4 bytes for the return value of `main` and set it to zero as per the C++(including C++11) standards. It generated the code for a `main` function that didn't need it. This is a side effect of not being optimized. Often an unoptimized compiler will generate code it may need, then doesn't end up needing it, and nothing is done to clean it up.

---

Because you are compiling with `-O0` there is a very minimum of optimizations done on code (`-O0` may remove dead code etc). Trying to understand artifacts in unoptimized code is usually a wasted exercise. The results of unoptimized code are extra loads and stores and other artifacts of raw code generation.

In this case `main` is special because in C99/C11 and C++ the standards effectively say that when reaching the outer block of `main` the default return value is 0. [The C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says:

> 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> 1 If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the
>   initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value
>   returned by the main function as its argument;11) **reaching the } that terminates the
>   main function returns a value of 0**. If the return type is not compatible with int, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

The [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says:

> 3.6.1 Main function
>
> 5) A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic
>   storage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. **If control reaches the end
>   of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing**
>
> ```
>  return 0;
> ```

In the version of CLANG++ you are using the unoptimized 64-bit code by default has the return value of 0 placed at `dword ptr [rbp-4]`.

The problem is that your test code is a bit too trivial to see how this default return value comes in to play. Here is an example that should be a better demonstration:

```
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    if (a > 3) return 5678;
    else if (a == 3) return 42;
}
```

This code has two exit explicit exit points via `return 5678` and `return 42;` but there isn't a final `return` at the end of the function. If `}` is reached the default is to return 0. If we examine the [godbolt output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+main()+%7B%0A++++int+a+%3D+3%3B%0A++++if+(a+%3E+3)+return+5678%3B%0A++++else+if+(a+%3D%3D+3)+return+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+foo()+%7B%0A++++return+1234%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.46397694524496,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B+-O0+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:70.23208879919274,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+5.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:29.767911200807262,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.24074074074074,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1504678313932:(undefined:(legend:!(11,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery3210325021482824634061:(display:''),sizzle1504678313932:(undefined:(legend:!(11,0,'1')))),length:1)),trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-O0+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:74.06659939455096,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:25.93340060544904,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:51.75925925925926,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),k:62.53602305475504,l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) we see this:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0        # Default return value of 0
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 3
        cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 3        # Is a > 3
        jle     .LBB0_2
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 5678     # Set return value to 5678
        jmp     .LBB0_5                       # Go to common exit point .LBB0_5
.LBB0_2:
        cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 3        # Is a == 3?
        jne     .LBB0_4
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 42       # Set return value to 42
        jmp     .LBB0_5                       # Go to common exit point .LBB0_5
.LBB0_4:
        jmp     .LBB0_5                       # Extraneous unoptimized jump artifact 
# This is common exit point of all the returns from `main`
.LBB0_5:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]      # Use return value from memory
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

As one can see the compiler has generated a common exit point that sets the return value (*EAX*) from the stack address `dword ptr [rbp-4]`. At the beginning of the code `dword ptr [rbp-4]` is explicitly set to 0. In the simpler case, the unoptimized code still generates that instruction but goes unused.

If you build the code with the option `-ffreestanding` you should see the default return value for `main` no longer set to 0. This is because the requirement for a default return value of 0 from `main` applies to a hosted environment and not a freestanding one.