# Can ASLR randomization be different per function?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, aslr

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t
esp_func(void)
{
  __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}

int
main()
{
  uint32_t esp = 0;

  __asm__("\t movl %%esp,%0" : "=r"(esp));

  printf("esp: 0x%08x\n", esp);
  printf("esp: 0x%08lx\n", esp_func());
  return 0;
}
```

Which prints the following upon multiple executions:

```
❯ clang -g  esp.c && ./a.out
esp: 0xbd3b7670
esp: 0x7f8c1c2c5140

❯ clang -g  esp.c && ./a.out
esp: 0x403c9040
esp: 0x7f9ee8bd8140

❯ clang -g  esp.c && ./a.out
esp: 0xb59b70f0
esp: 0x7fe301f8c140

❯ clang -g  esp.c && ./a.out
esp: 0x6efa4110
esp: 0x7fd95941f140

❯ clang -g  esp.c && ./a.out
esp: 0x144e72b0
esp: 0x7f246d4ef140
```

`esp_func` shows that ASLR is active with 28 bits of entropy, which makes sense on my modern Linux kernel.

What doesn't make sense is the first value: why is it drastically different?

I took a look at the assembly and it looks weird...

```
// From main
0x00001150      55             push rbp
0x00001151      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp
0x00001154      4883ec10       sub rsp, 0x10
0x00001158      c745fc000000.  mov dword [rbp-0x4], 0
0x0000115f      c745f8000000.  mov dword [rbp-0x8], 0
0x00001166      89e0           mov eax, esp            ; Move esp to eax
0x00001168      8945f8         mov dword [rbp-0x8], eax ; Assign eax to my variable `esp`
0x0000116b      8b75f8         mov esi, dword [rbp-0x8]
0x0000116e      488d3d8f0e00.  lea rdi, [0x00002004]
0x00001175      b000           mov al, 0
0x00001177      e8b4feffff     call sym.imp.printf     ; For whatever reason, the value in [rbp-0x8]
                                                       ; is assigned here. Why?


// From esp_func
0x00001140      55             push rbp
0x00001141      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp
0x00001144      89e0           mov eax, esp             ; Move esp to eax (same instruction as above)
0x00001146      488b45f8       mov rax, qword [rbp-0x8] ; This changes everything. What is this?
0x0000114a      5d             pop rbp
0x0000114b      c3             ret
0x0000114c      0f1f4000       nop dword [rax]
```

So my question is, what is in `[rbp-0x8]`, how did it get there, and why are the two values different?

Comment: 1.  because one is 32bit and another 64bits. 2. Noise from lack of optimization - compile it witl -O3 then analyse the code.

Comment: 3. Secong printf is an UB - use `ll` not `l`

Comment: ... and after sorting out UBs it is not as different: https://godbolt.org/z/achzrE

Comment: Many thanks @P__J__. That makes a lot of sense. What about this case: https://godbolt.org/z/sE7e84? The entropy bits are not the same, correct?

Answer (score 3):

No, stack ASLR happens once at program startup.  Relative adjustments to RSP between functions are fixed at compile time, and are just the small constants to make space for a function's local vars. (C99 variable-length arrays and `alloca` do runtime-variable adjustments to RSP, but not random.)

Your program contains Undefined Behaviour and isn't actually printing RSP; instead some stack address left in a register by the previous `printf` call (which appears to be a stack address, so its high bits do vary with ASLR).  It tells you nothing about stack-pointer differences between functions, just how not to use GNU C inline asm.

The first value is printing the current ESP correctly, but that's only the low 32 bits of the 64-bit RSP.

---

**Falling off the end of a non-`void` function is not safe**, and using the return value is Undefined Behaviour.  Any caller that uses the return value of `esp_func()` necessarily would trigger UB, so the compiler is free to leave whatever it wants in RAX.

If you want to write `mov %rsp, %rax` / `ret`, then write that function in pure asm, or mov to an `"=r"(tmp)` local variable.  Using GNU C inline asm to modify RAX without telling the compiler about it doesn't change anything; the compiler still sees this as a function with no return value.

MSVC inline asm is different: it is apparently supported to use `_asm{ mov eax, 123 }` or something and then fall off the end of a non-void function, and MSVC will respect that as the function return value even when inlining.  GNU C inline asm doesn't need silly hacks like that: if you want your asm to interact with C values, use Extended asm with an output constraint like you're doing in `main`.  Remember that GNU C inline asm is *not* parsed by the compiler, just emit the template string as part of the compiler's asm output to be assembled.

---

I don't know exactly why clang is reloading a return value from the stack, but that's just an artifact of clang internals and how it does code-gen with optimization disabled.  But it's *allowed* to do this because of the undefined behaviour.  It is a non-void function, so it needs to have a return value.  The simplest thing would be to just emit a `ret`, and is what some compilers happen to do with optimization enabled, but even that doesn't fix the problem because of inter-procedural optimization.

**It's actually Undefined Behaviour in C to *use* the return value of a function that didn't return one**.  This applies at the C level; using inline asm that modifies a register without telling the compiler about it doesn't change anything as far as the compiler is concerned.   Therefore your program as a whole contains UB, because it passes the result to `printf`.  That's why the compiler is allowed to compile this way: your code was already broken.  In practice it's just returning some garbage from stack memory.

TL:DR: this is not a valid way to emit `mov %rsp, %rax` / `ret` as the asm definition for a function.

(C++ strengthens this to it being UB to fall off the end in the first place, but in C it's legal as long as the caller doesn't use the return value.  If you compile the same source as C++ with optimization, g++ doesn't even emit a `ret` instruction after your inline asm template.  Probably this is to support C's default-`int` return type if you declare a function without a return type.)

---

This UB is also why your modified version from comments (with the printf format strings fixed), compiled with optimization enabled (https://godbolt.org/z/sE7e84) prints "surprisingly" different "RSP" values: the 2nd one *isn't* using RSP at all.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t __attribute__((noinline)) rsp_func(void)
{
  __asm__("movq %rsp, %rax");
}  // UB if return value used

int main()
{
  uint64_t rsp = 0;

  __asm__("\t movq %%rsp,%0" : "=r"(rsp));

  printf("rsp: 0x%08lx\n", rsp);
  printf("rsp: 0x%08lx\n", rsp_func());   // UB here
  return 0;
}
```

Output example:

```
Compiler stderr
<source>:7:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
Program returned: 0
Program stdout

rsp: 0x7fff5c472f30
rsp: 0x7f4b811b7170
```

`clang -O3 asm` output shows that the compiler-visible UB was a problem.  Even though you used `noinline`, the compiler can still see the function body and try to do inter-procedural optimization.  In this case, the UB led it to just give up and not emit a `mov %rsp, %rsi` between `call rsp_func` and `call printf`, so **it's printing whatever value the previous printf happened to leave in RSI**

```
# from the Godbolt link
rsp_func:                               # @rsp_func
        mov     rax, rsp
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     rsi, rsp
        mov     edi, offset .L.str
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        call    rsp_func               # return value ignored because of UB.
        mov     edi, offset .L.str
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf                 # printf("0x%08lx\n", garbage in RSI left from last printf)
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "rsp: 0x%08lx\n"
```

**GNU C Basic asm (without constraints) is not useful for anything (except the body of a `__attribute__((naked))` function).**

**Don't assume the compiler will do what you expect when there is UB visible to it at compile time.**  (When UB isn't visible at compile time, the compiler has to make code that would work for some callers or callees, and you get the asm you expected.  But compile-time-visible UB means all bets are off.)

Comment: *Falling off the end of a non-void function is UB.* No, it isn't.  The function simply returns an *unspecified value.*  Behaviour is only undefined if you make use of this result (cf. ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.91. ¶12.

Comment: @fuz: oh right, I keep mixing that up between C++ and C.  It is UB in C++; `gcc -xc++ -O3` omits the `ret` and just falls off the end.

Comment: @fuz the line `printf("esp: 0x%08lx\n", esp_func());` does make use of the result though, so in this case it should be UB.

Comment: @FelixG Indeed!  However, it's always best to be specific about what exactly is undefined behaviour lest people pick up wrong factoids.  I also recommend avoiding the acronym UB as it's not transparent to beginners and it's unclear if *undefined* or *unspecified* behaviour is meant.

Comment: Note that compilers do provide knobs to tweak undefined behaviour in compiler-specific ways. MSVC has __declspec(naked) for example, which (IIRC) tells it to just emit a `ret` and nothing else.

Comment: @user253751: Indeed, GNU C has `__attribute__((naked))`.  But I wouldn't say that "tweaks UB", it means the function body must consist entirely of `asm` statements, with *no* C.  You can't just use it on an existing function.  (And it doesn't even emit a `ret`; you might want your function to end with a tailcall `jmp`.)  From the optimizer's POV, it's basically like just having a prototype but no definition.  There are "tweaking UB" options, though, e.g. gcc/clang `-fwrapv` defines the behaviour of signed overflow (as 2's complement wraparound).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your input, but I was asking why this behaviour occurs since I'm studying compilers. I did not ask how to write clean code. You mentioned you don't know why this happens because "clang internals". I thank you, nonetheless, for taking the time to write your answer. It's well received, sir

Comment: @solidak: Your question title is "Can ASLR randomization be different per function?".  I was already updating when you commented to more directly answer that at the top of my answer, pointing out that your program isn't telling you anything about stack ASLR.  If you want to dig into clang / LLVM internals, they're open source, but don't expect the answer to be simple.  I did also add more detail about how inline asm interacts with C objects (including the return value object): at the C level it doesn't, unlike MSVC, unless you use GNU C Extended asm with output constraints.

Comment: @solidak: It might possibly be somewhat related to how un-optimized clang `-O0` handles the C99 / C++ implicit `return 0` at the bottom of `main`: by putting a `0` in some stack space, and never reading it if there is an explicit return.  [Unoptimized clang++ code generates unneeded "movl $0, -4(%rbp)" in a trivial main()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49300094).  But this is happening in a function not called `main`, so that's not it exactly.  Still, it might tell us something about the return value object.  I didn't want to speculate in my answer.

Comment: ASM with `volatile` can be useful on certain CPUs.

Comment: @user253751: GNU C inline asm with no output operands is implicitly `volatile`.  Otherwise the asm statement would get optimized away when nothing uses the (non-existent) result.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile.  (That's also true for GNU C Basic asm (no constraints at all))