# function of type double with no return

Tags: c, function

I want to represent the values of the sin function in the intervall 0 to 2Pi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double sinus(double lower, double upper, double step){
double i;
for(i=lower; i<=upper;i=i+step){
    
    printf("%13.3f%14.3f\n",i,sin(i));
}

}

int main () {

printf("        x-Value       y-Value\n\n");
sinus(0, 2 * M_PI,M_PI/8);


return 0;
}
```

Why does this work? The function sinus does not return a value of type double?

Comment: It doesn't "work", it invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: @UnholySheep As long as you don't use the returned value, it's not UB, in C.

Comment: Is there a way to get this right without using void instead of double?

Comment: @Boris Why don't you want it to be `double`? You don't generate a single value you'd want to return, so it makes sense to make it `void`-returning.

Comment: I don't see any UB here. `sinus` has no return, but we're not using the return value, so it just does its thing.

Comment: I know but the task says: I have to use this function double sinus(double lower, double upper, double step) for represting the values of  x and sin(x).

Comment: @Boris Are there more details on what you're supposed to do? It doesn't really make sense to return a `double` from a function that prints out a bunch of `double`s.

Comment: @KamilCuk See the comments below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62890546/5567382).

Comment: I want to compute  sin(x) in the intervall 0 to 2pi with stepsize pi/8. Therefore I have to use sinus(double lower, double upper, double step) , which I should call in main with its inital values 0,2pi,pi/8

Comment: @Boris That part makes sense, but what value do you intend to return from the function?

Comment: @Boris nobody is proposing that you have `void` function arguments - only its `return` type.

Comment: I am nit sure. In the end I should get some sort of table with x-values on the left an its matching y-values on the right side.

Comment: For void double would it be easy, but I do not get why I should use double sinus?

Comment: You shouldn't. There's something wrong with the problem statement.

Comment: I think so. Maybe it has to be void instead of double.

Comment: @all: Thank you very much for your help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this work? The function sinus does not return a value of type double?

It doesn't really *work*... my compiler (clang 11.0) gives a warning:

```
return.c:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

It works in the sense that it's not a compilation error (unless you set your compiler to treat warnings as errors). It works in the sense that you're not using the return value from `sinus()` anyway, so you don't really care what's in the return value.

If you *were* using the result from `sinus()`, then your code would be broken in the sense that it's not doing something meaningful. Depending on the compiler and the details of the program, you might always get the same return value, or you might get some random garbage value; either way, the value wouldn't be meaningful.

**TL/DR:** *Don't do that.*

> Is there a way to get this right without using void instead of double?

There are two obvious ways to fix the problem. You can leave the declaration of `sinus()` as is, and change the body to return a `double` to match the declaration:

```
double sinus(double lower, double upper, double step){
    double i;
    for(i=lower; i<=upper;i=i+step){
        printf("%13.3f%14.3f\n",i,sin(i));
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

Or, you can change the return type of `sinus()` so that you don't have to return anything:

```
void sinus(double lower, double upper, double step){
    double i;
    for(i=lower; i<=upper;i=i+step){
        printf("%13.3f%14.3f\n",i,sin(i));
    }
}
```

There's nothing in the implementation of `sinus()` that you seem to need to return, and no reason in `main()` to look at the return value, I'd go with the second option.

Comment: Thank you very much:) You made everything clear to me:)